# PHPWord - Why DOMElement::getAttribute() has warning

Tags: php, phpword

I wrote this code:

```
<?php

// load
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// want to load the file path
$source = __DIR__ . '/helloWorld.docx';

// load a DOCX file
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source, 'Word2007');         # Word2007

// output a docx file
$phpWord->save('test_out.docx');

?>
```

However, this error appears in the console:

> Warning: DOMElement::getAttribute() expects parameter 1 to be string,
> array given in /Users/USER_NAME/project/server/vendor/phpoffice
> /common/src/Common/XMLReader.php on line 140 PHP Warning:
> DOMElement::getAttribute() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
> given in /Users/USER_NAME/project/server/vendor/phpo
> ffice/common/src/Common/XMLReader.php on line 140

Why PHPWord appeared in these messages? I don't know why.

Comment: can you share the helloWorld.docx file? Also, did you try with the latest dev-develop version?

Comment: what was the last call in the stacktrace to your own code? `IOFactory::load()` ?